# Changing from mysqli to PDO did not work?

Tags: php, pdo

I previously used mysqli and now i would like to use PDO instead but I did not echo any result from my database. I have read so many articles about PDO tutorial but they teach different things. I tried to pick piece by piece and came up with this code, but i did not echo any result from my database or throw any error.

```
try{
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM memberpost ORDER BY poststart DESC LIMIT       $start_from,$num_rec_per_page");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if(count($row)>0){
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo $row['title']."<br>";
}
}
else{
 echo "NO result found";
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is my database connect code:

```
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', $username, $password); //new PDO 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: how is $conn assigned to a connection? please show that code  something like $conn=new PDO()

Comment: why are you calling ->fetch() twice? You never use the $row from the first call, meaning you're losing a row of data. Doing count() on that row would only tell you how many fields were fetched anyways. It has NOTHING to do with how many rows were matched by the query.

Comment: Rather just do a plain `foreach ($stmt as $row) {` iteration.

Comment: any error?? try fetch all and see what result you get..

Comment: So how to rewrite it so that: it will check how many results drawn from the query. And if, result > 0, do while loop, else echo some error?

Comment: add an `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before db script to see what errors you've got

Answer (score 0):

Edit your database connection code to this:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

And try this code in your .php file :

```
$sth = $conn->prepare(SELECT * FROM memberpost)
$sth->execute();
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($red);
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this on the internet, it might help:

```
// defining query 
$sql = 'SELECT name, surname, zip FROM table';  

// showing results
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){  
  echo $row['name']. '<br>';    
  echo $row['surname']. '<br>';  
  echo $row['zip']. '<br>';  
}
```

Source (ita): http://www.mrwebmaster.it/php/guida-utilizzo-pdo_7594_4.html